# What does this mean: map (1 + )

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I mean, I know what it means: take the list and add 1 to each element in it; that is, it's equivalent to `map (1 + _ )`.  What I don't understand is how Scala *knows* it's equivalent.  What's going on here?

**Edit**

Daniel points out it's a more general question.  For example

```
def g(f : Int => Int, x : Int) = f(f(x))
g( (1 + ), 2)
res12: Int = 4
```

Which is cool.  Every day I find a new useful thing that Scala can do.  I guess what I'm looking for a full description (and ideally a name) of this particular *thing*.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/135

Comment: Thanks, but it's easy to see how a function with several parameter lists would become a curried function when the last list is omitted, but that isn't really the case here.

Comment: The language spec calls this "eta expansion", an implicit conversion for unapplied methods. See http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf section 6.26.2

Answer (score 8):

It goes a bit like this:

1. `map` expects a function `Int => B` (in this case).
2. `1 +` doesn't resolve to a function `Int => B`, so try other things.
3. `1 +` can be lifted from a method expecting an `Int` parameter to a function `Int => Int`.

Presto.

One uses `1 + _` to solve ambiguity.